# Can I make a query in elastic search that groups and sorts a nested field this way?

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to create a complicated query in elastic search that aggregates and groups nested data. The structure of my documents is as follows.

```
_source: {
    _id: some id
    …Etc (data other than RECORDS in source is irrelevant to what I am trying to do)
    RECORDS: [
        {
      Record_id: some id
      status: some status
      source: (can be USER or other values)
      createdBy: (email of the user that created this record)
      createdDate: (date this record was created in millisecond format) 
        }
    ]
}
```

Each document can have any number of objects in the RECORDS nested field. The query I have been asked to write would have to get all of the RECORDS objects in the last 14 days with a source of USER and a certain status (we will say the status value I want is APPROVED) (from any document, not just one document), and group them by createdDate, and createdBy.

So I need all of the records from any document that:

1. Are from only the last 14 days
2. Have a source of USER
3. Have a status of APPROVED

And I need to group them all by createdBy and createdDate(by day, while the records are in millisecond format) in descending order by date.

So say I had 2 documents that each contain a RECORDS field with the following objects:

```
[
  { status: REMOVED, source: USER, createdBy: user1@gmail.com, createdDate: 1683901320000}, 
  { status: APPROVED, source: AUTOMATIC, createdBy: user2@gmail.com, createdDate: 1684074120000},
  { status: APPROVED, source: USER, createdBy: user2@gmail.com, createdDate: 1684074120000},
  { status: APPROVED, source: USER, createdBy: user2@gmail.com, createdDate: 1684075980000},
  { status: APPROVED, source: USER, createdBy: user1@gmail.com, createdDate: 1684075980000}
],
[
  {status: APPROVED, source: USER, createdBy: user1@gmail.com, createdDate: 1684075500000}, 
  { status: APPROVED, source: USER, createdBy: user2@gmail.com, createdDate: 1684248300000}, 
  { status: APPROVED, source: USER, createdBy: user1@gmail.com, createdDate: 1684334700000}, 
  { status: APPROVED, source: USER, createdBy: user1@gmail.com, createdDate: 1684332780000}, 
  { status: APPROVED, source: AUTOMATIC, createdBy: user1@gmail.com, createdDate: 1684075980000}
]
```

Then what I want from the query would be a list that looks like this:

```
[
  {day: May 17, user: user1@gmail.com, recordCount: 2},
  {day: May 16, user: user2@gmail.com, recordCount: 1},
  {day: May 14, user: user2@gmail.com, recordCount: 2},
  {day: May 14, user: user1@gmail.com, recordCount: 2}
]
```

Is this something that is possible to do with elastic search and with nested fields, and if so, how?

I have tried in the past to query elastic search this way but have had no success. Right now I have it just finding all of the documents within the last 14 days and I am filtering, grouping, and sorting them in Java, which is obviously not ideal performance wise because I can be dealing with thousands of these record objects at once.